# Running multiple Django tests via one ./manage.py test command causes error, running each individually does not

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a series of unit tests (all subclasses of TransactionTestCase) spread out through multiple apps in a single Django project.  When I run all of them in one go using `./manage.py test` an error occurs in one of the tests.  But when I run each app's tests individually, one at a time, using `./manage.py test my_project.app_name` I get no errors.

The specific error I get is a FieldError in modelform_factory, but my question isn't so much about the specific solution to this error.  I'm just curious what possible data/processes/whatever could bleed over between the supposedly-self-contained test cases in Django.  Any thoughts?

(For the curious, if I make all my tests subclasses of TestCase (rather than TransactionTestCase) I get a bunch of different errors, but I've chalked those up to some separate issue relating to problems with rolling back the transactions within which Django encapsulates each test case.  But who knows, maybe there's a connection?)

Comment: I've seen something like this before. Can you post your project file layout?

Comment: Afraid I can't - it's not mine to share.  But I resolved the issue.  Thanks for reading though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Regardless of how many different test cases are run during one `./manage.py test` call, and regardless of how much the database is rolled back/truncated (for TestCase and TransactionTestCase, respectively) between tests, all tests are run under *the same python thread* and with *the same instantiations of all model base classes*.  Thus any variables in the thread or any modifications to class definitions persist across test instances.

In my case, it was both.  A view got a user instance out of the currently running thread, but that user had been deleted when a previous test had been rolled back.  Later on a view modified a list that was declared (as a blank list) in its parent class, thus altering the parent classes list to not be a blank list, and causing problems in a later test.